# CSS Grid Elements not Resizing with Window Resize

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-grid

Beginner with Grid here. I'm doing a small project for "target" practice. The problem I ran into is, the grid does not resize on smaller screens. However, if I remove the display grid from the container, and put a display flex on it, the problem solves. What is causing my grid container not to resize? I am very sorry if it's such a noob question, I'm a beginner with Grid.

Under this, there's a code, whereas *main* is the grid container, which I was referring to earlier. Above *main*, there's another grid container, with nothing, but just display grid and gap defined. If I set *main* to display flex, problem solves. What causes my grid container *main* to behave like this? By the way I am using Tailwind, but it should not make any difference.

Thank you so much!

````
   <main class="grid grid-cols-12 auto-rows-auto gap-16" style="
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
">
        <section class="grid grid-cols-12 col-start-1   col-end-13 gap-8">
            <article class="grid grid-cols-12 auto-rows-auto lg:col-start-1 lg:col-end-9 col-start-1 col-end-13 gap-8">
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-13">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="/src/assets/image-web-3-desktop.jpg"><img
                            src="/src/assets/image-web-3-mobile.jpg" alt="Web 3 Hero Image for Mobile" width="100%">
                    </picture>
                </div>
                <div class="grid grid-cols-12 col-start-1 col-end-13 gap-6">
                    <div class="col-start-1 col-end-7">
                        <h1 class="text-very-dark-blue font-bold text-6xl">The Bright Future of Web 3.0?</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col items-start gap-8 col-start-7 col-end-13">
                        <p class="text-dark-grayish-blue lg:pr-2">We dive into the next evolution of the web that claims
                            to put the power of the platorm back into the hands of the people. But is it really
                            fulfilling its promise?</p><a
                            class="inline-block transition-colors hover:bg-very-dark-blue uppercase text-off-white bg-soft-red font-semibold text-[12px] tracking-[.425rem] px-8 py-4"
                            href="#">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <aside
                class="flex flex-col gap-6 lg:col-start-9 lg:col-end-13 col-start-1 col-end-13 bg-very-dark-blue py-8 px-6">
                <h2 class="text-soft-orange font-bold text-4xl">New</h2>
                <div>
                    <article
                        class="[&amp;:not(:last-child)]:pb-10 [&amp;:not(:first-child)]:pt-10 [&amp;:not(:last-child)]:border-b border-grayish-blue">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3 class="transition-colors hover:text-soft-orange text-off-white font-bold text-lg">
                                Hydrogen VS Electric Cars</h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="text-grayish-blue text-sm">Will hydrogen-fueled cars ever catch up to EVs?</p>
                    </article>
                    <article
                        class="[&amp;:not(:last-child)]:pb-10 [&amp;:not(:first-child)]:pt-10 [&amp;:not(:last-child)]:border-b border-grayish-blue">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3 class="transition-colors hover:text-soft-orange text-off-white font-bold text-lg">The
                                Downsides of AI Artistry</h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="text-grayish-blue text-sm">What are the possible adverse effects of on-demand AI image
                            generation?</p>
                    </article>
                    <article
                        class="[&amp;:not(:last-child)]:pb-10 [&amp;:not(:first-child)]:pt-10 [&amp;:not(:last-child)]:border-b border-grayish-blue">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3 class="transition-colors hover:text-soft-orange text-off-white font-bold text-lg">Is VC
                                Funding Drying Up?</h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="text-grayish-blue text-sm">Private gunding by FV firms is down 50% YOY. We take a look
                            at what that means.</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </section>
        <section class="grid article-cards col-start-1 col-end-13 gap-10">
            <article class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-6">
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-5"><img src="/src/assets/image-retro-pcs.jpg" alt="Retro PCs image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-5 col-end-13 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-between"><span
                        class="font-bold text-grayish-blue text-3xl">01</span><a href="#">
                        <h3 class="transition-colors hover:text-soft-red font-bold text-very-dark-blue">Reviving Retro
                            PCs</h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="text-dark-grayish-blue text-sm">What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-6">
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-5"><img src="/src/assets/image-top-laptops.jpg" alt="Top laptops image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-5 col-end-13 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-between"><span
                        class="font-bold text-grayish-blue text-3xl">02</span><a href="#">
                        <h3 class="transition-colors hover:text-soft-red font-bold text-very-dark-blue">Top 10 Laptops
                            of 2022</h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="text-dark-grayish-blue text-sm">Our best picks for varius needs and budgets.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-6">
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-5"><img src="/src/assets/image-gaming-growth.jpg"
                        alt="Gaming growth image"></div>
                <div class="col-start-5 col-end-13 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-between"><span
                        class="font-bold text-grayish-blue text-3xl">03</span><a href="#">
                        <h3 class="transition-colors hover:text-soft-red font-bold text-very-dark-blue">The Growth of
                            Gaming</h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="text-dark-grayish-blue text-sm">How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </main>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it was the gap attribute across the x axis that made it overflow. Solved.